# Change font family programmatically in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, font-family

I'm creating a WPF application.

I have created a folder in my solution and I have some fonts in it.

How can I change programmatically the TextBlock **FontFamily** ?

Comment: What have you tried to achieve your wanted results? What has your research concerning your problem shown? Can you provide code of your tries? [How do I ask a good question](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How much research effort is expected](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) might be helpful to improve your question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

XAML

```
<TextBlock 
  Name="textBlock"

  Background="AntiqueWhite" 
  Foreground="Navy" 

  FontFamily="Century Gothic"
  FontSize="12"
  FontStretch="UltraExpanded"
  FontStyle="Italic"
  FontWeight="UltraBold"

  LineHeight="Auto"
  Padding="5,10,5,10"
  TextAlignment="Center"
  TextWrapping="Wrap"

  Typography.NumeralStyle="OldStyle"
  Typography.SlashedZero="True"
>
  <Run Background="LightGreen">Text run 1.</Run>
  <LineBreak/><Run Background="LightBlue">Text run 2.</Run>
  <LineBreak/><Run Background="LightYellow">Text run 3.</Run>
</TextBlock>
```

Code behind

```
TextBlock textBlock = new TextBlock(new Run("A bit of text content..."));

textBlock.Background              = Brushes.AntiqueWhite;
textBlock.Foreground              = Brushes.Navy;

textBlock.FontFamily              = new FontFamily("Century Gothic");
textBlock.FontSize                = 12;
textBlock.FontStretch             = FontStretches.UltraExpanded;
textBlock.FontStyle               = FontStyles.Italic;
textBlock.FontWeight              = FontWeights.UltraBold;

textBlock.LineHeight              = Double.NaN;
textBlock.Padding                 = new Thickness(5, 10, 5, 10);
textBlock.TextAlignment           = TextAlignment.Center;
textBlock.TextWrapping            = TextWrapping.Wrap;

textBlock.Typography.NumeralStyle = FontNumeralStyle.OldStyle;
textBlock.Typography.SlashedZero  = true;
```

if you want to load a custom font

```
controlID.FontFamily = new FontFamily("file:///Font
 Full Path");
```

Answer (score 0):

Take the Control e.g. a TextBlock and set its style with

```
Style style = new Style(typeof(TextBlock));
```

Then add a setter using a resource as follows

```
style.Setters.Add(new Setter(TextBlock.FontFamilyProperty, this.FindResource("NameOfResource")));
```

Finally set the style to the control...

```
myTextBlock.Style = style;
```

Answer (score 0):

**App.xaml:**

```
<Application.Resources>
    <FontFamily x:Key="samim">/Resources/Fonts/samim.TTF#Samim</FontFamily>
</Application.Resources>
```

use font in your **Window (or Page) code**:

```
lblTitle.FontFamily = (FontFamily)FindResource("samim");
```